# Greedy algorithm: highest value first vs earliest deadline first

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, job-scheduling, greedy

Assume we have a set of `n` jobs to execute, each of which takes unit time. At any time we can serve exactly one job. Job `i`, `1<=i<=n` earns us a profit if and only if it is executed no later than its deadline.

We can a set of jobs feasible if there exists at least one sequence that allows each job in the set to be performed no later than their deadline. "Earliest deadline first" is feasible.

**Show that the greedy algorithm is optimal**: Add in every step the job with the highest value of profit among those not yet considered, provided that the chosen set of jobs remains feasible.

**MUST DO THIS FIRST:** show first that is always possible to re-schedule two feasible sequences (one computed by Greedy) in a way that every job common to both sequences is scheduled at the same time. This new sequence might contain gaps.

**UPDATE**

I created an example that seems to disprove the algorithm:

Assume 4 jobs:

- Job A has profit 1, time duration 2, deadline before day 3;
- Job B has profit 4, time duration 1, deadline before day 4;
- Job C has profit 3, time duration 1, deadline before day 3;
- Job D has profit 2, time duration 1, deadline before day 2.

If we use greedy algorithm with the highest profit first, then we only get job B & C. However, if we do deadline first, then we can get all jobs and the order is CDB

Not sure if I am approaching this question in the right way, since I created an example to disprove what the question wants

Comment: Sounds like you're asking us to do your homework. What have you tried so far, what language is this in, and where's your actual question?

Comment: I only see an imperative, not a question.

Comment: There's no particular language that I am using. This is just a general question I am trying to proof but have no idea. I created an example that seems to disprove the algorithm:

Comment: so where's the question?

Comment: Assume 4 jobs: Job A has profit 1, time duration 2, deadline before day 3; Job B has profit 4, time duration 1, deadline before day 4; Job C has profit 3, time duration 1, deadline before day 3; Job D has profit 2, time duration 1, deadline before day 2. If we use greedy algorithm with the highest profit first, then we only get job B & C. However, if we do deadline first, then we can get all jobs and the order is CDAB

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 the question is to show and prove that the greedy algorithm is optimal

Comment: what work have you done so far to prove this? Also, this probably doesn't belong in a software dev / coding forum

Comment: you can't get CDAB since the total cost is 5?

Comment: seems you can only get CDB.

Comment: Oops, you are right. Only CDB. However, my point is still valid since "earliest deadline first" gets more profit than "highest profit first"

Comment: @JamestheGreat So please correct your question description and see my answer:)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is called Job sequencing with deadlines, and can be solved by two algorithms based on greedy strategy:

1. Sort input jobs decreasing on profit. For every job put it in list of jobs of solution sorted increasingly on deadline. If after including a job some jobs in solution has index grater than deadline, do not include this job.
2. Sort input jobs decreasing on profit. For every job put it in the list of job of solution on the last possible index. If there is no free index less or equal to the job deadline, do not include the job.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, neither "earliest deadline first", "highest profit first" nor "highest profit/duration first" are correct algorithm...

Assume 2 jobs:

- Job A has profit 1, time duration 1, deadline before day 1;
- Job B has profit 2, time duration 2, deadline before day 2;

Then "earliest deadline first" fails to get correct answer. Correct answer is B.

Assume another 5 jobs:

- Job A has profit 2, time duration 3, deadline before day 3;
- Job B has profit 1, time duration 1, deadline before day 1;
- Job C has profit 1, time duration 1, deadline before day 2;
- Job D has profit 1, time duration 1, deadline before day 3;
- Job E has profit 1, time duration 1, deadline before day 4;

Then "highest profit first" fails to get correct answer. Correct answer is BCDE.

Assume another 4 jobs:

- Job A has profit 6, time duration 4, deadline before day 6;
- Job B has profit 4, time duration 3, deadline before day 6;
- Job C has profit 4, time duration 3, deadline before day 6;
- Job D has profit 0.0001, time duration 2, deadline before day 6;

Then "highest profit/duration first" fails to get correct answer. Correct answer is BC (Thanks for @dognose's counter-example, see comment).

One correct algorithm is Dynamic Programming:

First order by deadline ascending. `dp[i][j] = k` means within the first `i` jobs and within `j` time units we can get `k` highest profit. Then initially `dp[0][0] = 0`.

Jobs info are stored in 3 arrays: profit are stored in `profit[i], 1<=i<=n`, time duration are stored in `time[i], 1<=i<=n`, deadline are stored in `deadline[i], 1<=i<=n`.

```
  // sort by deadline in ascending order
  ...
  // initially 2 dimension dp array are all -1, -1 means this condition unreachable
  ...
  dp[0][0] = 0;
  int maxDeadline = max(deadline); // max value of deadline
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
      for(int j=0;j<=maxDeadline;j++) {
          // if do task i+1 satisfy deadline condition, try to update condition for "within the first i+1 jobs, cost j+time[i+1] time units, what's the highest total profit will be"
          if(dp[i][j] != -1 && j + time[i+1] <= deadline[i+1]) {
              dp[i+1][j+time[i+1]] = max(dp[i+1][j+time[i+1]], dp[i][j] + profit[i+1]);
          }
      }
  }
  // the max total profit can get is max value of 2 dimension dp array
```

The time/space complexity (which is `n*m`, `n` is job count, `m` is maximum deadline) of DP algorithm is highly dependent on how many jobs and the maximum deadline. If `n` and/or `m` is rather large, it maybe difficult to get answer, while for common use, it will work well.

Comment: *highest profit/duration first* is not always "best". Take the jobs `A,B,C,D` with the values`{duration,profit}`: `A: {4,6}, B: {3,4}, C: {3,4}, D:{2,0.0001}` - All with the deadline in 6 days. In this case, you'd better run the two `3-day` jobs, (earning 8) rather than a `4-day` (and `2-day`) job (earning 6,0001) even if the ratio of the 4 day job is best (1.5 vs 1.3).

Comment: @dognose Yes you are right, thank you for raising this counter-example! I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, but I realize we must show that the Greedy Algorithm with highest profit first is optimal. MUST DO THIS FIRST: show first that is always possible to re-schedule two feasible sequences (one computed by Greedy) in a way that every job common to both sequences is scheduled at the same time. This new sequence might contain gaps.

Comment: @JamestheGreat Sorry I do not understand your updated comment... Could you give an example? As answer mentioned, highest profit first is not always right.

Comment: Yes my example shows that highest profit is not always right, but it appears that highest profit is a better algorithm than earliest deadline in most cases. So we need to prove that by doing the MUST DO THIS FIRST

Comment: And I am having trouble doing that, so I was hoping I could get some guidance

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks like **Job Shop Scheduling**, which is NP-complete (which means there's no optimal greedy algorithm - despite that experts are trying to find one since the 70's). [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2zweB9JD7c) on a more advanced form of that use case that is being solved with a Greedy algorithm followed by Local Search.

If we presume your use case can indeed be relaxed to Job Shop Scheduling, than there are many optimization algorithms that can help, such as Metaheuristics (including Local Search such as Tabu Search and Simulated Annealing), (M)IP, Dynamic Programming, Constraint Programming, ... The reason there are so many choices, is because none are perfect. I prefer Metaheuristics, as they out-scale the others in all the research challenges I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JOB {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    char name[]={'1','2','3','4'};
    int dl[] = {1,1,4,1};
    int profit[] ={40,30,20,10};

    char cap[] = new char[2];
    for (int i =0;i<2 ;i++)
    {
        cap[i]='\0';
    }

    int j;
    int i =0;

    j = dl[i]-1;

    while (i<4)
    {

        if(j<0) {
            i++;
            if(i<4)
            j = dl[i]-1;
        }
        else if(j<2 && cap[j]=='\0')
        {
            cap[j] = name[i];
            i++;
            if(i<4)
            j = dl[i]-1;

        }
        else
           j=j-1;

    }

    for (int i1 =0 ; i1< 2 ; i1++)
        System.out.println(cap[i1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.